# about combo box column of datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a standard DataGridView. One of the columns is aDataGridViewComboBoxColumn. When I select one of the ComboBox items, I wantto trap the change and add text in other column based on the data selected

Answer (score 0):

Set the combo box to auto post back and provide an implementation for the onselectedindexchanged event.